# how to showing text field when select option is changed jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried showing / appending a textfield when some condition in my select option is true, the problem is, it's not just a one select option, it's more than one so it make me confused...

it is my HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
        <option>Checked</option>
        <option>UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
        <option>Checked</option>
        <option>UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
        <option>Checked</option>
        <option>UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>
```

my Jquery :

```
$(document).on("change", ".select", function(){
   var value = $(".select").val();
   if(value == "Checked"){
       var input = "<input type='text' name='test'>";
       $(".select").html(input);
   }
});
```

my code is not working, even the `input` is not showed...

any help will be very very appreciated

Comment: instead of $(".select").val() try $(this).find( "option:selected" ).text()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `this` to get current changed select. Also use `next` to get the span in which you want to add input.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".select", function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   if(value == "Checked"){
   var input = "<input type='text' name='test'>";
   $(this).next('.text_area_appended_here').html(input);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2">
<select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
    <option>Checked</option>
    <option>UnChecked</option>
</select>
<span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
    <option>Checked</option>
    <option>UnChecked</option>
</select>
<span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
    <option>Checked</option>
    <option>UnChecked</option>
</select>
<span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little with the assumption that you would like to show the text box whenever the value of a select item is "Checked".

```js
$(document).on("change", ".select", function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   if(value == "1"){
       var input = "<input type='text' name='test'>";
       $(this).parent().find(".text_area_appended_here").html(input);
   } else {
       $(this).parent().find(".text_area_appended_here").empty();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
        <option value="">Select something</option>
        <option value="1">Checked</option>
        <option value="0">UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
        <option value="">Select something</option>
        <option value="1">Checked</option>
        <option value="0">UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
        <option value="">Select something</option>
        <option value="1">Checked</option>
        <option value="0">UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this. Below code will take value of selected "Select box" and append your input to  next to selected "Select box"

```
$(document).on("change", ".select", function(){
   var value = $(this).val(); //change
   if(value == "Checked"){
       var input = "<input type='text' name='test'>";
       $(this).next().html(input ); //change
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').on("change", function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   if(value == "Checked"){
       var input = '<input type="text" value="'+$(this).val()+'" name="test">';
       $(this).parent('div').append(input);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
    <option>---</option>
        <option>Checked</option>
        <option>UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
      <option>---</option>
        <option>Checked</option>
        <option>UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="check[]" class="form-control select">
    <option>---</option>
        <option>Checked</option>
        <option>UnChecked</option>
    </select>
    <span class="text_area_appended_here"></span>
</div>
```

try this one. I hope it helps you.