# How to Append Input in different Div Jquery using MULTIPLE Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say i have html code like this :

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='section1'>
            <select name='language[]' class='language' id='language'>
                <option>English</option>
                <option>Mandarin</option>
                <option>Others</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='section2'>
            <select name='status[]' class='status'>
                <option>Active</option>
                <option>Pasive</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='section3 append_here'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='section1'>
            <select name='language[]' class='language' id='language'>
                <option>English</option>
                <option>Mandarin</option>
                <option>Others</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='section2'>
            <select name='status[]' class='status'>
                <option>Active</option>
                <option>Pasive</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class='section3 append_here'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the purpose of my code is, when language is `English`, it will shown another field for scores. and when the language is `Others`, it will show(append) another field for input the language

i tried like this on my jquery :

```
$("body").on("change", "#language", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 'English'){
        var input = `<input type='text' placeholder='input your score here !'>`;
        $(this).next('.append_here').show().html(input);
    }else if(value == 'Others'){
        var input = `<input type='text' placeholder='input your language here !'>`;
        $(this).next('.append_here').show().html(input);
    }else{
        $(this).next('.append_here').hide().empty();
    }
});
```

i dont have a problem when i just using a single `select language option`, the problem is, if the `select language option` is more than one, the `html()` function works to all of the field....

any help will be very appreciated

thanks btw

Comment: Do you mean that if you add `Multiple` then your code does not work?

Comment: yes, for example if the first one is `others field`, and when i add one more to `english`, the first one become the english field (all of them)

Comment: i hope people understand what is my purpose :(

Comment: I've added a answer below, but what would you like to happen when you select all 3 of the options`?

Comment: Instead of `$(this).next('.append_here')` in your code, you can use `$('.append_here')` directly to display input fields.

Comment: @DarkCode999 It's really confusing to understand what you want.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen my case almost like my question before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880199/how-to-showing-text-field-when-select-option-is-changed-jquery/45880413#45880413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go a working example:
You should not use identical id's use classes instead, and then get index for the current element.

```js
$("body").on("change", ".language", function(){
    var index = $(this).index(".language");
    var value = $('.language:eq( '+index+' )').val();

    if(value == 'English'){
        var input = `<input type='text' placeholder='input your score here !'>`;
        $('.append_here:eq( '+index+' )').show().html(input);
    }else if(value == 'Others'){
        var input = `<input type='text' placeholder='input your language here !'>`;
        $('.append_here:eq( '+index+' )').show().html(input);
    }else{
        $('.append_here:eq( '+index+' )').hide().empty();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class='section1'>
      <select name='language[]' class='language' id='language1'>
        <option>Choose language</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Mandarin</option>
        <option>Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='section2'>
      <select name='status[]' class='status'>
        <option>Active</option>
        <option>Pasive</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='section3 append_here'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class='section1'>
      <select name='language[]' class='language' id='language2'>
        <option>Choose language</option>
        <option>English</option>
        <option>Mandarin</option>
        <option>Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='section2'>
      <select name='status[]' class='status'>
        <option>Active</option>
        <option>Pasive</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='section3 append_here'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what a simple and elegant answer... very thanks to you sir ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have some selector issue in your code. Check updated snippet below..

```js
$("body").on("change", "#language", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    if(value == 'English'){
        var input = "<input type='text' placeholder='input your score here !'>";
        $('.append_here').show().html(input);
    }else if(value == 'Others'){
        var input = "<input type='text' placeholder='input your language here !'>";
        $('.append_here').show().html(input);
    }else{
        $('.append_here').hide().empty();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class='section1'>
        <select name='language[]' class='language' id='language'>
            <option>English</option>
            <option>Mandarin</option>
            <option>Others</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='section2'>
        <select name='status[]' class='status'>
            <option>Active</option>
            <option>Pasive</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='section3 append_here'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry sir, i said `multiple` is for the `select option` not for `the item in select option`... i said above, if the select is just one, i dont have a problem... but if the select option is more than one is really confused :( ... thanks for trying to help btw